# event passed to debounce firing continuously (not debouncing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, underscore.js, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

Here's the code:

```
lookup_book = (obj) ->
  $.get '/list_items/retrieve_google_book/' + obj.val() + '/' + obj.attr("id")
  return

delayed_lookup = (obj) ->
  _.debounce(lookup_book(obj), 3000)
  return

$(document).on 'keyup', '.list-item-title', (event) ->
  delayed_lookup($(this))
  return
```

I want lookup_book and therefore the ajax request to only fire if the user has not typed for 3000ms. Right now it fires as I am typing the letters in the input field, without any sort of delay.

What's going on here? I'm pulling my hairs out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a function into _.debounce, you are actually calling the function lookup_book every time the 'keyup' event is triggered.

So _.debounce returns a new function for you to call.

```
delayed_lookup = _.debounce(lookup_book, 3000)

$(document).on 'keyup', '.list-item-title', (event) ->
  delayed_lookup($(this))
  return
```

Comment: Edits reflect what I think the code was intended to do

Comment: I see where the error is now. The problem that remains is that I need to access `$(this)` inside `lookup_book`. How would I go about that?

Comment: I fiddled around with it a bit more and I figured out that `_.debounce()` does need the -> to declare it as a function. I will post my solution that I got to work using a custom debounce implementation. I couldn't figure out where the problem was here.

Comment: _.deboucne returns a new function that you're supposed to call. You can pass $(this) into the delayed function. What was the issue you came across?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom implementation of debounce because I was not able to get the above to work.

```
delay = do ->
  timer = 0
  (callback, ms) ->
    clearTimeout timer
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms)
    return

$(document).on 'keyup', '.list-item-title', (event) ->
  val = $(this).val()
  id = $(this).attr("id")
  delay (->
    $.get '/list_items/retrieve_google_book/' + val + '/' + id
    return
  ), 2000
  return
```